# isc-dhcp-server fails to start at boot

Tags: dhcp

I have been running the isc-dhcp-server fine for quite a while. A few days back after an update, it fails to start. I found a few more people reporting similar problems but that was from 2009. I was unable to find the logs of the isc-dhcp-server process either. However, if I manually start the dhcp server as `sudo service isc-dhcp-server start', it runs just fine.

The following is the output of `dmesg | grep isc-dhcp-server`

```
[   15.267804] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1201) terminated with status 1
[   15.267839] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.334785] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1352) terminated with status 1
[   15.334821] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.492463] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1359) terminated with status 1
[   15.492496] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.550789] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1366) terminated with status 1
[   15.550826] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.608956] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1380) terminated with status 1
[   15.608990] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.660740] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1387) terminated with status 1
[   15.660774] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.719178] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1402) terminated with status 1
[   15.719213] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.769204] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1409) terminated with status 1
[   15.769239] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.819264] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1416) terminated with status 1
[   15.819301] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.869196] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1430) terminated with status 1
[   15.869232] init: isc-dhcp-server main process ended, respawning
[   15.910841] init: isc-dhcp-server main process (1437) terminated with status 1
[   15.910873] init: isc-dhcp-server respawning too fast, stopped
```

I am using Mint 13.

`Linux hostname 3.2.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 10:48:16 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What could be wrong? How do I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar discussion [here](http://forum.zentyal.org/index.php?topic=12160.0), that mentions adding a sleep value to delay the start.  They mention adding the following to /etc/rc.local helped to start it on boot:

```
sleep 10000
/etc/init.d/zentyal start
```

but a smaller value such as `sleep 10` may work.  Sounds like your service may be `/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server` and not `/etc/init.d/zentyal`, but same idea.

I'm not sure if `/etc/rc.local` applies to Linux Mint, but another option is to add the `sleep 10` to the init.d script itself as the first command.

Comment: Is that not going to add 10 seconds to my boot time??

Comment: Yes.  I've used this hack for something years ago for a service that was failing on boot.  Looking into it deeply, we found that the networking, even though it started *before* said service, wasn't actually ready for use.  So adding a `sleep` value to our service, we were able to give the networking time to actually be ready for use.  It is indeed a workaround, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: On this particular machine, the dhcp server is binding to an adapter that has a static IP. Does your concept still apply? Can a network adapter with a manually specified static IP have start up latencies?

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it seems to work just fine. Is there a way to sleep only if the interface is not yet up? and retry this look a few times before abandoning?

I am not a shell script wizard :-(

Comment: Just to document - I modified the `/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf` script and added a `sleep 2` just before the `exec` of the server.
Are these scripts executed asynchronously? My network interfaces seem to come the last on the `dmesg` list @ ~27 - 30 seconds :-(

Comment: Glad it worked.  In general, rc (i.e. startup or init) scripts such as network should be synchronous.  Commands can be 'backgrounded' (typically with a '&' at the end of the command), so it depends on whats in the particular script, but networking specifically *should* finish before continuing on with the boot process as many services are dependent upon it.  Also, check where in the boot order the isc-dhcp-server script is, as you could start it later in the boot process.  Mint is Ubuntu-based, so perhaps this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) would help.